# Does having tables and materialized views in differnt schemas in Redshift have any performance impact?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, query-optimization, data-warehouse

My data warehouse is being migrated to Redshift. The original system has various tables and materialized views in several different schemas (same database).
My question, Will this structures, spreading my db elements across different schemas, has any performance impact in Redshift?
There is quite a few queries with joins between different schemas.